# Javascript Private Method Issue

Tags: javascript, oop

I imagine that the error below is pretty easy to fix for someone who is not a  newb ( like me)

Can anyone tell me why the call to "this.slideNext() " in the code below does not work.    Apparently "this.slideNext() " is not a function?

```
function ScoopAnimation(_path, _start, _end, _delay) {

    this.start = _start
    this.end = _end;
    this.delay = _delay;
    this.path = _path
    this.currentFrame = _start;

    this.slideNext() = function() {
        this.currentFrame++;
        console.log('  next this.currentFrame  : ' + this.currentFrame);
    }

    this.start = function() {
        console.log('next this.start()   : ' + this.currentFrame);
        //THE NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ERROR!
        this.slideNext()
    }

    this.start();

}
```

Comment: looks like you have your semicolons missing. can you try if the error persists when you add your semicolons? Furthermore, can you post the error message? You can see it from Web Console in Firefox, for example.

Comment: Gotcha. Semicolons weren't the problem . The error message is "this.slideNext is not a function" . Japrescott's solution removes the error. It looks like I had an extra set of paraenthesis ;)

Answer (score 1):

no, that line you flaged as "the bad one" is actually correct.
further up, you are trying to execute the slideNext function and then assign a function to the result. it should be this;

```
this.slideNext = function (){
    this.currentFrame ++;
    console.log('  next this.currentFrame  : ' +this.currentFrame );
}
```

hope i helped

Comment: you weren't fast enough for a "bounty hunter", but since you're in for the points, here you go!

Comment: no, i dont care about the points, but if my answer is correct and I spent time writing it, wanting some recognition seems legit to me :)
(and since you don't care about points, why not donate them to me? :P)

Comment: sry, you 're right. I'm trying not to encourage the "points race". but you're right. your answer is good => upvote

Comment: japrescott, thanks, that worked (alas, I just registered and don't have enough points to upvote. Otherwise, I would).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but shouldn't it be defined as:

```
// defined without brackets
this.slideNext = function (){
    this.currentFrame ++;
    console.log('  next this.currentFrame  : ' +this.currentFrame );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` has a different reference/context for each function, based on how the function is invoked. In your snippet, you're calling the `start` function() which (called just like that) will reference the `global object` in its `this context variable` for non-ES5 strict and `undefined` in ES5 strict.

To solve that problem, you can either store the reference for your "outer" `this` in a local variable, like

```
var myScope = this;
```

and then use `myScope` instead of `this` within any other function context you need to access the outer scope.

```
myScope.slideNext();
```

Another option would be to use ES5 `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the context for a function. This would look like:

```
this.start = function() {
    console.log('next this.start()   : ' + this.currentFrame);
    //THE NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ERROR!
    this.slideNext()
}.bind(this);
```

Now, we bound the current value of `this` to the context of the `start` function. Now you can just continue to use `this` within the function. Notice that this will only work for js engines that support ES5 or you have loaded some kind of ES5 Shim script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It helped me better understand "this" in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend on ScoopANimation being used as a constructor, then I'd personally ditch the use of 'this':

```
function ScoopAnimation(_path, _start, _end, _delay) {

  var start = _start,
      end = _end,
      delay = _delay,
      path = _path,
      currentFrame = _start;

    function slideNext() {
      currentFrame++;
      console.log('  next this.currentFrame  : ' + currentFrame);
    }

    function start() {
      console.log('next this.start()   : ' + currentFrame);
      //THE NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ERROR!
      slideNext()
    }

    start();
}
```